# MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL Returns TypeError at /mySite/ coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found

Tags: python, django, unicode

I am trying to allow image uploading on my site but having trouble at the very onset.

My file structure:

```
mySite/
    myApp/
        templates
        media
        __init__.py
        admin.py
        model.py
        forms.py
        urls.py
        views.py
```

Now I want to include `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL`:

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
MEDIA_ROOT = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')]
MEDIA_URL = '/images/'
```

But when refresh my page, Django template returns **TypeError at /mySite/
coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found**

How can I get this to work? Thank you already.

Comment: You're specifying your `TEMPLATE_DIRS` and `MEDIA_ROOT` as lists; you don't need those square brackets.

Comment: @dazedconfused: This solved it. And I hope I am doing it the right way?